# Generated wallets on testnet receive no transactions

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, testnet, balance, deterministic-wallet

I have set up my own testnet. When I generate a new wallet by using `monero-wallet-cli --testnet --restore-deterministic-wallet` and providing a seed, it works as expected. Wallets receive both mined and transferred coins.

However, if I create a new wallet using `monero-wallet-cli --testnet` in an empty dir, the new wallet doesn't see any incoming transaction and balances are 0/0. `refresh` command doesn't help.

Then I issue `seed` command, copy the words away, exit client, delete all wallet files and start again by `monero-wallet-cli --testnet --restore-deterministic-wallet` and paste the seed I copied. Suddenly, the wallet now refreshes transactions as expected an calculates its balances properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely the bug fixed in https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/2542. If you can't or won't patch your copy to include this small fix, a workaround is to ensure you have a synced daemon when you create the wallet, so that monero-wallet-cli can access it to query the current blockchain height.

Comment: I recompiled monero with that patch, but it doesn't help. Time to file a bug.